# Online collection of the world languages' melodic patterns?

Tags: pronunciation, resource-request, prosody

Every language has some very typical melodic patterns and I've been wondering is there some sort of a global repository collecting and comparing such patterns?

Comment: By "melodic pattern", do you mean "intonation"?

Comment: I don't know about online repositories, but you might want to try an introduction handbook to prosody and intonation, and see if they discuss a bunch of different languages. There are some books specifically comparing the intonation of many languages (like [Ah-Jun's](http://gep.ruhosting.nl/carlos/sunah_venlo_helden[9].pdf)), but they tend to be a bit technical.

Comment: @ user6726 - maybe yes. I checked several definitions of "intonation" and I am not quite sure if that is the same. What I mean is this: when you hear somebody speaking a given language, you'd notice that some typical patterns of melody reappear at the point that you could sing them out without using any words, just as a melody.

Comment: @melboiko - I am rather interested in the melodies themselves rather than the theoretical explanations how they are being produced vocally. That is, I am looking for a "playlist" of various melodies :)